# Restkit with basic authentication and specific API path

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit, basic-authentication

I have a strange problem about restkit and basic authentication..
I would to call an API server using the basic authentication:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myHost:8000/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:httpClient];

// Setup the object mappings
        RKObjectMapping *userMapping = .....
//

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:theMapping
         method:RKRequestMethodGET
         pathPattern:@"/api/test"
         keyPath:nil
         statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
        [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


- (void) testAPI {
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"test" password:@"test"];
    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/test"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                /// Success

                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                /// Failure
                            }];

}
```

With this code I have this error about BasicAuth:

```
E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200), got 401" UserInfo=0xb49d420 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0xd834880> { URL: http://myHost:8000/api/test }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myHost:8000/api/test, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200), got 401, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xdc92ae0> { URL: http://myHost:8000/api/test/ } 
{ status code: 401, headers {
    Allow = "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 21 Dec 2013 17:17:22 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3";
    Vary = Accept;
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"api\"";
} }}
```

If I not use the path /api/test but I use the root api (I not a specific path) I not have this basic Auth problem.
Why RestKit work only root API server with basic authentication?
I use RestKit 0.20.3